# How does a pointer to virtual function differ from a pointer to a non-virtual one?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, virtual

And why is it required to use "&" before function in the next piece of code?

```
void (Mammal::*pFunc) () const=0;
pFunc=&Mammal::Move;
```

Move() is a virtual function in the basic class and pFunc is a pointer to virtual function in this class.
So why we need to use "&"? According to some special properties of virtual function?
Or it is simply syntax?

Comment: Using pointers to member functions generally doesn't end well

Comment: We need to use `&` because the standard says so.

Comment: There is no syntactic difference between  pointer to virtual function and a pointer to a non-virtual member function. They are implemented differently under the hood, but the programmer should not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary function can be called with just its address, so a pointer to an ordinary function is just an address.

A non-virtual function can also be called with just its address (plus, of course, the `this` pointer, passed by whatever mechanism the compiler uses), so a pointer to a non-virtual function could be just an address.

A virtual function has to be looked up by a compiler-specific mechanism (usually a vtable, at a known offset in the object; the address of the function is found by indexing into the table), and a pointer to virtual function has to contain whatever information is needed to determine what the actual function to call is, depending on the actual type of the object.

But a pointer to member function has to be able to handle **both** virtual and non-virtual functions, so it will have enough room for the right mechanism for both, and the runtime call will check the stored data to figure out what to do.

Some compilers provide an alternative, where if you promise that you will absolutely, positively, **never** store a pointer to virtual function in the pointer, the compiler will generate a smaller pointer representation, and you'll find that you're in trouble later when you break that promise.

As to why the `&` is required, it's required. Microsoft's early C++ compilers didn't require the `&` (and didn't require the class name; if you left it out you'd get a pointer to the member function of the class of the current object); they talked about proposing eliminating the rule, but it didn't get anywhere.

Comment: I thought pointers to virtual member functions were usually handled by a thunk, so all member function pointers use the same representation. Member data pointers are where the dragons live.

Comment: @AlanStokes - could be, on some implementations. That's not required, though. It's been many years since I paid attention to this kind of detail, so I'm not up on the latest implementation techniques or how widely used they are.

Answer (score 0):

& is the address-of operator.  While in C it is possible to simply specify the name of the function without this, in C++ you are supposed to use it with a fully qualified function name.

If I remember correctly, when you take the address of a virtual function, the compiler will actually generate an intermediate function, the address of which will then be used instead.  When that intermediate function is called, all it will do is call the virtual function you specified.

Comment: In C++ the & and class name are required for member functions. C doesn't have member functions at all so doesn't have any syntax for referencing them. Both languages allow referencing a non-member function without the &.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line, pFunc isn't a pointer to a virtual function, it's a pointer to a const method in Mammal that takes no arguments and returns void. You are then assigning 0 to that pointer.

The '&' operator is giving you the address of the Mammal::Move method in class scope, suitable for assigning to a member function pointer.

The standard requires the '&' operator, though I have used compilers that didn't require it.

Comment: Compilers might differ in how good they represent the standard, but the standard for sure requires the `&` on memberfunctions.